# Calling Fortran DLL from C# with Open() call

Tags: c#, dll, fortran

I'm calling a Fortran DLL from C# code. All works fines for the code shown below and I well receive the correct return value at my C# side.

However, as soon as I uncomment the line `open(31, file='output.txt', status='new')`, I get the following exception:

> System.DllNotFoundException: 'Unable to load DLL 'MyProgram.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)'

Same result for all calls I try to make to the Fortran `read()` and `write()` functions.

For info; I'm compiling with `gfortran` installed via `mingw-w64`.

```
        function return_integer(input) result(output)

            ! Don't leave the calling convention to chance.
            !GCC$ ATTRIBUTES CDECL ::  return_integer
        
            integer*4, intent(in) :: input
            integer*4 :: output

            ! open(31, file='output.txt', status='new' )

            output = 2*input+1


        end function
```

Comment: Also looking at Dependency Walker no DLLs seems to be missing. If I compile to exe instead of dll, the open() call works perfectly.